# DateTime.Parse date format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date represented as a string thus

```
20130116154407
```

I called DateTime.Parse on this but it failed.  How can I convert this to a DateTime?  Incidentally the timezone is CET.

**EDIT**

The solutions provided are very useful, so far but it seems they do not support 24 hour clocks, still looking for a solution that does.

**EDIT 2**

The correct format is

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify a format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I still get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
string DATE_FORMAT= "yyyyMMddhhmmss";

DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(str, DATE_FORMAT, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
//success
//you can use date
}else
{
//fail
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20130116154407", "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```